# Upgade Parallels Plesk Panel from version 9.3.0 to 11.0.9 (Latest Version)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, plesk

I want to upgrade Parallels Plesk Panel on Server. My server details are:

```
Parallels Plesk Panel version: 9.3.0
Operating system: Linux 2.6.18-028stab107.1
CPU: GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Xeon(R)CPU L5506 @ 2.13GHz
```

I want to know that can we upgrade Plesk Panel 11.0.9 (Latest Version) on this version of OS or should i need to upgrade OS also and what the risk to upgrade Plesk ?

Comment: This is completely off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0):

In-place upgrade it's always risky because of a lot of server customizations.

The most safest upgrade approach it is [upgrade through transfer](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-installation-upgrade-migration-guide/71242.htm). It's when you install new panel instance(I'm not sure maybe you need new license or trial license for this new panel, ask Parallels sales) and use Migration manager to transfer you data from old panel instance to new one.

In case of any critical issues Parallels has program of [free assistance for Parallels Plesk Panel 11 Transfer/Migration](http://www.parallels.com/support/plesk/free11assistance/)

I recommend you to upgrade to 11.5.30, it's stable now.